# How can I use Angular views inside of an ASP.Net MVC 4 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to use Angular.JS to implement multiple contact forms, but am not sure how to keep angular's routing from interfering with ASP.Net's routing.

My ASP.Net MVC 4 routes look like this (this is the default project with minor alterations):

```
namespace Angular_Test
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I would like my contact page's (located at `/contact`) `ng-view` div to default to something like (say) `form.html`, and have a handful of links that would load in `form2.html`, `form3.html`, etc. But would pointing those links to something like `/contact/form2` totally screw with ASP.Net's routes? How should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure that all URLs mapped to Angular views are handled by the same route on the server (i.e. server should return `/contact` if it gets a request to either `/contact`, `/contact/form1`, `/contact/form2`, etc.)

Comment: What should ASP.Net's route look like then? `url: "{action}/*"` (is that a valid route)? Also - thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think `{action}/{*pathInfo}` should work. `{*whatever}` will catch any number of segments after `{action}`. In your case I'd create a route for `contact/{*pathInfo}` pattern

Answer (score 1):

I prefix my angular view routes with '/partials'.  It looks like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "DefaultPartials",
     "partials/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Now keep in mind that this approach will cause a partial view to go through the entire page life cycle but I use razor partials for localization of my page text so this is ok for my usage.

Then I use areas in my application to spit out JSON data from Web API controllers for angular to consume.  Keeps things nice and tidy.  Hope this helps.

I almost forgot.  You will want to put the partials route just before the standard default route in RouteConfig.cs.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! This doesn't fit my exact use case here (because of the reload) but this will definitely be helpful in the future and is a super nice way to organize this. Thanks!

Comment: One other note on the benefit of using razor for angular partials. You can create angularjs html helpers for your forms and client side validation. As I am sure you have discovered typing out an angular form element and accompanying validation fields can be quite a chore.  Razor helpers cut that time in half and allows you to use validation frameworks like FluentValidation.